# Delay spring xml imports

Tags: spring, spring-java-config

I have an application where I have to read all application properties from properties files. Then override them from a external cache framework. Then initialize spring beans.

I am using Java Config of spring to read properties and override them. And using @import to load xml files. But xml files import as soon as context starts loading, resulting all the xml beans being initialized.

So is there a way I can delay xml files import until I load all the properties first?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code.

```
<beans default-lazy-init="true">
<!-- no beans will be pre-instantiated... -->
 </beans>
```

or individually add lazy-init on beans which you don't want to load.

Or

There are lot of ways you can achieve your requirement One of which can be use of `depends-on` or @DependsOn if you are looking for annotation based configuration,

You can read property file after that you can create a cache bean and use 
depends-on to let the container know you bean is depending on some other bean you can initialise a cache bean and use the same as you see fit.

See this [example](http://www.concretepage.com/spring/example_dependson_spring) for better clearity.

```
<bean id="primaryBean" depends-on="cacheBean"></bean>
```

Now IoC guarantees that depending bean will be created before the bean which depends on this bean, So you will have an instance of this bean, and can use it.

Other than this you can implement `LifeCycle` interface

```
public interface Lifecycle {

    void start();
    void stop();
    boolean isRunning(); 
}
```

For more references you can refer [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-lifecycle).

Comment: Thanks Vipul, but the catch is I cannot modify the spring xml beans which I am about to import. So I cannot add lazy init or depends-on in those xml files

Comment: Use @DependsOn annotation instead of xml approach.